# How to avoid break columns when to print page

Tags: printing

I'm using css to creat columns with result query inside divs, but when I'm trying print the lasts divs every break, how to avoid this?

**css:**

```
     .div-em-colunas {
     -webkit-column-count:4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     -moz-column-count:4;    /* Firefox */
      column-count:4;         /* padrão */
```

**html**

```
     <div class="div-em-colunas" >
     <div align="center" style="border-style: ridge;height:90px;"><b><?=$linha['user']?></b></br><?=$linha['name']?>
     </div>
</div>
```

image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the page break inside property on any element you don't want to be page broken.

```
    page-break-inside: avoid;
```

See the MDN documentation for more details on how to create a print stylesheet. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing